# Callback in writeCapture

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script which I load this way:

```js
$(funcion() {
    var html = ''
    html += '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/test.js"></script>'

    $('#divid').html(writeCapture.sanitize(html,function(){
        // if my test.js returns special content i do this:

        var cap = ''
        cap += '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/example.js"></script>'
        $('#divid').html(writeCapture.sanitize(cap))
    })
})
```

But I have error NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is "writeCapture"? And please accept answers to your guestions!!!

Comment: https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture

Answer (score 1):

Don't load scripts like that. Use the [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function instead:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('http://example.com/test.js', function() {
        // the script is loaded here => you can use it
    });
});
```

Comment: With this plugin i replace `document.write` and `getScript` is bad solution for me

Comment: because script which is appended with `document.write` also has some `document.write` and it has to append content of each `document.write` into the specific div.

Comment: same problem rsboarder. Any news with this?